# login twitter in android

Tags: java, android, twitter, account

I am new to programming in android and I would like to make an app in java that allows me to enter the application through my twitter account. So far I have not been able to find much current information that helps me, it is worth mentioning that I want to do the configuration between android studio and twitter and not occupying other tools like back4pp as I have researched so far. Hopefully you can help me, thanks in advance!.this is what I currently have in my app:
1.loggin.class: it is a main loggin window where the user can register to the app through google
2.main.class: contains a navigation drawer and also allows you to change the fragments by selecting any option in the drawer.
3.perfil_user.class: this is a fragment that contains the view of the user profile to which the application redirects you after registering or clicking on the google button.

main.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    //variables para cargar el fragment
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);//se pasa el toolbar
        drawerLayout=findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        navigationView=findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        actionBarDrawerToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.open,R.string.close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
        //cargar fragment principal
        FragmentManager fragmentManager;
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
        fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, new perfil_user());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.user){
            FragmentManager fragmentManager;
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
            fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new perfil_user());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }
        else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.exit){
            finish();
        }
        //aquí van las otros fragment
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return false;
    }
}
```

loggin.class

```
public class loggin extends AppCompatActivity {
    //variables google
    Button register;
    SignInButton signInButton;
    TextView recoveruser,recoverpassword;
    GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    int RC_SIGN_IN=0;
    //variables fb
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    LoginButton loginButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loggin);
        register=findViewById(R.id.buttonregister);
        recoveruser=findViewById(R.id.recoveruser);
        recoverpassword=findViewById(R.id.recoverpassword);
        signInButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        callbackManager= CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        loginButton =  findViewById(R.id.login_button);
         signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 switch (v.getId()) {
                     case R.id.sign_in_button:
                         signIn();
                         break;
                     // ...
                 }
             }
         });
        //configuración para google:
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build();
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);


    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {

            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(task);
        }
    }
    private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);

             Intent intent=new Intent(loggin.this,MainActivity.class);
             startActivity(intent);
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.

        } catch (ApiException e) {

            Log.w("error", "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());

        }
    }
 }
```

fragment:

```
public class perfil_user extends Fragment {
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.perfil_user,container,false);
            GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
            GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build();
            mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(getContext(),gso);
            ImageView imageView=view.findViewById(R.id.image_user);
            TextView nameuser=view.findViewById(R.id.NameUser);
            TextView email=view.findViewById(R.id.setmail);
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getContext());
            if (acct != null) {
                String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
                String personEmail = acct.getEmail();
                Uri personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();
                nameuser.setText(personName);
                email.setText(personEmail);


            }

            return  view;

        }

    }
```

Comment: successfully logged?

Comment: no, not yet, I need to connect to twitter but I don't know how to do it hehe, that's why I ask someone to help me to do it or at least give me the bases to achieve it since currently there is not much info on the internet

Comment: follow this  http://www.tutorialsface.com/2020/05/integrating-google-sign-in-into-android-app-sample-example-tutorial/

Comment: Friend, that tutorial is to log in with google in the app, I want to log in with my twitter account in my project.

Comment: lookout this, https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/twitter-login-android-tutorial-integrating-twitter-login/